# Sorting one array by another array and appending unknown missing items

Tags: javascript, sorting

Say I have an order which is just an ordered list that references the array of objects with a sectionId. 
I'd like the items missing from the order list to be appended to the end of the sorted array. However my example below the missing items are put at the top of the list - help appreciated!

```js
const orders = [
[
    "one", 
    "two",
    "three",
],
[
    "two",
    "three",
    "one", 
],
[
    "three",
    "one", 
    "two",
]
]

const sections = {
0: [
    {
        "sectionId": "a"
    }, 
    {
        "sectionId": "two"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "z"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "three"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "one"
    }, 
],
1: [
    {
        "sectionId": "a"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "three"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "one"
    }, 
    {
        "sectionId": "z"
    }, 
    {
        "sectionId": "two"
    },
], 
2: [
    {
        "sectionId": "z"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "a"
    }, 
    {
        "sectionId": "two"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "three"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "one"
    }, 
]
}

const outcomes = {
0: [
    {
        "sectionId": "one"
    }, 
    {
        "sectionId": "two"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "three"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "a"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "z"
    }, 
],
1: [
    {
        "sectionId": "two"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "three"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "one"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "a"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "z"
    }, 
],
2: [
    {
        "sectionId": "three"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "one"
    }, 
    {
        "sectionId": "two"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "z"
    },
    {
        "sectionId": "a"
    }, 
],
}

// function
const generateOrderedSections = (sections, order) => {
return sections.sort((a, b) => {
    const aIndex = order.indexOf(a.sectionId)
    const bIndex = order.indexOf(b.sectionId)
    const sortOrder = aIndex > 0 && aIndex > bIndex ? 1 : -1
    // console.log(aIndex, a.sectionId, bIndex, b.sectionId, sortOrder)
    return sortOrder;
})
}

// test cases
orders.forEach((order, index) => {
const section = sections[index]
const test = generateOrderedSections(section, order)
const result = JSON.stringify(test)
const outcome = JSON.stringify(outcomes[index])

if (result === outcome) {
    console.log(index, 'passed')
} else {
    console.log('-------------')
    console.log('failed')
    console.log('-------------')
    console.log('expected')
    console.log(outcomes[index])
    console.log('\nresult')
    console.log(test)
}
})
```

Comment: why comes `'z'` before `'a'` in thei first part?

Comment: Fixing the test case now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add one tho the index, and this yields zero (for unknow indices) and take a default value of a large number to sort this items to the end.

```js
const
    orders = [["one", "two", "three"], ["two", "three", "one"], ["three", "one", "two"]],
    sections = { 0: [{ sectionId: "a" }, { sectionId: "two" }, { sectionId: "z" }, { sectionId: "three" }, { sectionId: "one" }], 1: [{ sectionId: "a" }, { sectionId: "three" }, { sectionId: "one" }, { sectionId: "z" }, { sectionId: "two" }], 2: [{ sectionId: "z" }, { sectionId: "a" }, { sectionId: "two" }, { sectionId: "three" }, { sectionId: "one" }] },
    outcomes = { 0: [{ sectionId: "one" }, { sectionId: "two" }, { sectionId: "three" }, { sectionId: "a" }, { sectionId: "z" }], 1: [{ sectionId: "two" }, { sectionId: "three" }, { sectionId: "one" }, { sectionId: "a" }, { sectionId: "z" }], 2: [{ sectionId: "three" }, { sectionId: "one" }, { sectionId: "two" }, { sectionId: "z" }, { sectionId: "a" }] },
    generateOrderedSections = (sections, order) => {
        return sections.sort((a, b) =>
            ((order.indexOf(a.sectionId) + 1) || Number.MAX_VALUE) -
            ((order.indexOf(b.sectionId) + 1) || Number.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    };

// test cases
orders.forEach((order, index) => {
    const section = sections[index]
    const test = generateOrderedSections(section, order)
    const result = JSON.stringify(test)
    const outcome = JSON.stringify(outcomes[index])

    if (result === outcome) {
        console.log(index, 'passed')
    } else {
        console.log('-------------')
        console.log('failed')
        console.log('-------------')
        console.log('expected')
        console.log(outcomes[index])
        console.log('\nresult')
        console.log(test)
    }
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I seem to get all results ordered the same as: one, two, three unfortunately

Comment: sorry, i missed some parentheses.

Comment: Thank you :) Great job makes sense and is concise